# a blank page when deplying substrate smart contract

Tags: polkadot, ink, blockchain

am using the guide here https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/

To deploy the flipper after filling the second form as required i the page goes blank

The black page consoler log is

```
Uncaught Error: The runtime does not expose api.tx.contracts.instantiateWithCode with storageDepositLimit
at new Base$1 (polkadot.4d4418f9.js:5:29341)
at new Code (polkadot.4d4418f9.js:5:32770)
at new CodePromise (polkadot.4d4418f9.js:5:33828)
at pS (index.a53e7976.js:160:53012)
at index.a53e7976.js:254:13061
at il (react.ec1551b3.js:32:24312)
at Gn (react.ec1551b3.js:32:42382)
at id (react.ec1551b3.js:32:41193)
at gn (react.ec1551b3.js:32:40232)
at Fi (react.ec1551b3.js:32:36884)
```

instantiate:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your source? A minimal reproducible example is best to help

Comment: This might be the reason for your problem: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/substrate-tutorial-blank-page-when-deploying-smart-contract