# Substrate tutorial: Blank page when deploying smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I am following the Substrate tutorial at https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/

I was able to build/compile the Flipper smart contract but when I'm trying to deploy the contract using contracts-ui I'm getting a blank page

[image]

In addition to that when running `substrate-contracts-node --dev` I see that no block is produced.

Only log line produced is:

[image]

Do you think this is an expected behavior for the node?
Not sure what I'm missing or if the issue might be related with the substrate node or the substrate contracts ui.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest `substrate-contracts-node` uses a new type for `Weight`. The UI is not yet updated to handle those changes. This is also mentioned in the release notes: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases/tag/v0.22.1. I recommend sticking with `0.21.0` for now.